# How to submit ideas for the Ubuntu Apps Showdown to reddit?

Tags: application-development

I submitted 4 app ideas, but only one pass through to [the list on reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/ubuntuappshowdown/), the others 3 even not searchable:

- [Medication Tracker](http://redd.it/vje7o)
- [TrelloChat](http://redd.it/vjhid)
- [TwilioPhone](http://redd.it/vjggr)

I also submitted the blog post, firstly it went through to the list, but disappeared the next day.

Am I missed anything?

**UPDATE:**

At least I'm not alone with this issue, see comments on the following wrap-up's:

- [Ubuntu App Showdown Week 1 Wrap-Up](http://developer.ubuntu.com/2012/06/ubuntu-app-showdown-week-1-wrap-up/)
- [Ubuntu App Showdown Week 2 Wrap-Up](http://developer.ubuntu.com/2012/06/ubuntu-app-showdown-week-2-wrap-up/)

Comment: They are not on reddit. Did you sign up for an account so you could post?

Comment: @jonobacon, here is my reddit account: http://www.reddit.com/user/yevgenko/

Comment: @jonobacon could you please clarify, the ideas can be reached by direct URL, can vote for ideas... all ideas displayed as under ubuntuappshowdown, e.g. "submitted 2 days ago by yevgenko to ubuntuappshowdown", but not displayed under ubuntuappshowdown list...

Comment: @jonobacon, here is the only idea which pass through to the list [Hassle Free PC Synchronization](http://redd.it/vjfll)

Comment: @jonobacon, I'm sorry to bother you but could you advice what should I do to get my ideas visible on reddit? I just tried to submit one more idea and it also not visible...

Comment: I think I have the same problem:
http://redd.it/vvhq1 This link isn't in the ubuntuappshowdown reddit list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that all those posts got stuck as spam.

I've now moderated the spam queue and accepted them. Let us know if you've got further problems with posting links.